# How to access data of text files in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, command-line

I am trying to create a command line todo list using Javascript. For that I have two text files todo.txt and done.txt. After adding todo, it should be stored in todo.txt and after calling done function with the index it should delete the respective todo from todo.txt and store that todo in done.txt. I have created below program to do the same. But I am getting an error: data.splice is not a function i.e. object:anonymous. Please tell me what changes I need to made in the below code?

```
var fs = require('fs');

//constants
var todo_file = "todo.txt";
var done_file = "done.txt";


function init(){
    if(!fs.existsSync(todo_file)){
        console.log("Creating `todo.txt` file");
        setTodo([]);    
    }
    if(!fs.existsSync(done_file)){
        console.log("Creating `done.txt` file");
        setDone([]);    
    }
}

function getTodo(){
    //read file contents
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(todo_file);
    return contents;
}

function getDone(){
    //read file contents
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(done_file);
    return contents;
}

function setDone(data){
    //write to  file
    fs.writeFileSync(done_file);
}
function setTodo(data){
    //write to  file
    fs.writeFileSync(todo_file);
}

//display usage
function usage() {
    console.log("Usage: done [add|check|delete|help] [task]");
    console.log("`task` is only a string when using `add` and a number\nfor all other commands.");
    console.log("Using the `done` without arguments lists all tasks");
}

//add task
function add(task) {
    //get data
    var data = getTodo();

    //add item
    data.push({task:task,completed:false});

    //set data
    setTodo(data);

    //list
    list();
}

//check task
function done(task) {
    //get data
    var data = getTodo();
    var done = getDone(); 
    //modify the data (toggle)
    done = data.splice(task,task+1);

    //set data
    setTodo(data);
    setDone(done);
    //list
    list();
}

//delete task
function del(task){
    //get data
    var data = getTodo();

    //delete item
    data.splice(task,task+1);

    //set data
    setTodo(data);

    //list
    list();
}

//list all tasks
function list() {
    
    //data
    var data = getTodo();
    
    if(data.length > 0){
        //print the list. using ANSI colors and formating
        console.log("\x1b[93m\x1b[4mTask list:\x1b[24m");
        data.forEach(function (task,index){
            console.log(index+1+"."," ["+(task.completed ? "\x1b[92m✓\x1b[93m" : " ")+"] ",task.task);
        });
        
    }else{
        console.log("\x1b[91mNo tasks added!!");
    }

}


var command = process.argv[2];
var argument = process.argv[3];

init();

switch(command){
    case "add":
        add(argument);
        break;
    case "done":
        done(argument-1);
        break;
    case "delete":
        del(argument-1);
        break;
    case "help":
        usage();
        break;
    case "list":
        list();
        break;
    default:
        console.log("\x1b[91mCommand not found!!\x1b[0m");
        usage();
        break;
}
```

Comment: You can't store Javascript arrays inside files directly, you will need to serialise your data.  use JSON.stringify & JSON.parse to serialise the data to & from your filesystem.  Ps.  There are lots of ways to serialise your data, JSON is just the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

As Keith typed, you shouldn't store Javascript arrays inside files directly, you should serialize your data instead. JSON.stringify & JSON.parse are a good option to serialize the data as they are the simplest method.

Comment: I have modified my code. Can you check it once and tell me how should I write delete function taking index as a parameter.